# Incorrect delay results in modelsim

Tags: delay, verilog, modelsim

I am trying to model a full adder with gate delays in modelsim. For simplicity, here's a self-contained simple testbench:

```
module simple_delay;
  reg x, y, cin;
  wire a,b,c, s, cout;

  // simple structural full adder
  xor #1 XO1(a, x, y);
  and #1 A1 (b, x, y);
  xor #1 XO2(s, cin, a);
  and #1 A2 (c, cin, a);
  or  #1 O1 (cout, c, b); 

  initial
  begin
    x= 1'b1; y = 1'b1; cin = 1'b0;
    #10 $stop;
  end
endmodule
```

I would expect the outputs a and b to become available after one delay unit, outputs `c` and s after one more delay (total 2) and finally `cout` after one more delay (total 3). Instead `cout` also is valid after 2 delays.

Is this due to short-circuit boolean evaluation? Since `b` becomes one after one delay, `cout` will be 1 regardless of the value of `c` which is still unknown (x). Is this how the simulator works? If so, how can I disable this (I did not find anything relevant in the documentation and disabling optimizations doesn't fix it).

Can I force modelsim to not be smart and actually delay the calculation of `cout` by one unit?

Answer (score 0):

`c` will be zero at time 1 because `cin` is low; with an AND gate if any input is low the others are don't care and the output is low. So `b` and `c` will both have know values at time 1. Therefore `cout` will have the correct value by time 2.

The worst case delay is 3 and is observed when `cin` is high and `a&b==0`. All other input conditions will have a delay of 2.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the ModelSim is "smart", it's the simulated gate is smart enough to  calculate the output once only part of the inputs is "known". Don't forget, that it is "unknown to you, but it is actually `0` or `1`, and the gate "sees" it along with the "known" input some time before, and then calculating it. This is what will happen in the actual hardware.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the simulator works, as described in the IEEE Std 1800-2012, Table 28-3 "Truth tables for multiple input logic gates".  If any input to the `or` gate is 1, the output will be 1.

You could create your own or-gate module to force the output to be x if any input is x:

```
assign out = $isunknown({a,b}) ? 1'bx : a|b;
```